# project field in MongoDB with I don't know intermediates field name

Tags: mongodb

1. Document like in JSON

```
    {
      "matchs":{
        "aus":{
          "won":[2019, 2020],
          "lose":[2018, 2017]
        },
        "pak":{
          "won":[2002, 2003, 2004],
          "lose":[]
        }
      }
     }
```

2. I want to select won match in every country
3. Like "match.*.won" in $project or $match condition
4. like

   ```
    db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{"matchs":{"*.won":{$exists:true}}}}])
   ```
5. Output like:

   `[{"matchs":{"aus":{"won":[2019, 2020]},"pak":{"won":[2002, 2003, 2004]}}]`

Comment: I know this structure is very complex but I want won datas from the collection and how i filter that from mongoDB

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filter for `won`, it would be quicker to delete `lose`. Would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { matchs: { $objectToArray: "$matchs" } } },
   { $unset: "matchs.v.lose" },
   { $set: { matchs: { $arrayToObject: "$matchs" } } }
])
```

Or if you prefer `$set`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { matchs: { $objectToArray: "$matchs" } } },
   {
     $set: {
       "matchs": {
         $map: {
           input: "$matchs",
           in: { k: "$$this.k", v: {won: "$$this.v.won" } }
         }
       }
     }
  },
  { $set: { matchs: { $arrayToObject: "$matchs" } } }
])
```

Comment: Getting error while using this query. Error was -  Unrecognised pipeline state name ` $set

Comment: `$set` was introduced in version 4.2, use `$addFields` instead.